# make a KML/KMZ layer transparent/opaque

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have been looking for a while for a simple way to make a KML/KMZ layer transparent/opaque using the Google Map API version 3.  There are plenty of example out there, but there doesn’t seem be a simple example of making a KML layer opaque.  I have provided an example below, can someone help me out with this???

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Example 2</title>
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// ***Initialize the Map Function ***
function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 10,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

var polyLayerOptions = {
    supressInfoWindows: true,
    Opacity: 0.15
};
var polyLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer
('http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml', polyLayerOptions);
polyLayer.setMap(map);
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

There isn't an opacity flag in the KML options, but you can set the color of objects in your KML to be transparent. Google uses a 32 bit color in the form ABGR, where the first byte is the alpha channel or transparency and the next three bytes are regular colors (though not in the standard RGB order that everyone else uses!). For example, a color of #80FF0000 would be a 50% transparent Blue. There doesn't seem to be a way to modify the transparency on the fly in code like you can in Google Earth, you have to update the KML and repost it to your map.